# How does Caltrain check whether cars parked at Caltrain stations belong to Caltrain customers?

Tags: usa, trains, automobiles, california, northern-california

I read on http://www.caltrain.com/riderinfo/Parking.html ([mirror](http://archive.is/A9ehq)):

> Parking is available for Caltrain customers at most Caltrain stations.

How does Caltrain check whether cars parked at Caltrain stations belong to Caltrain customers?

---

From https://www.parkme.com/en-gb/lot/187135/mountain-view-station-mountain-view-ca, found by [Nate Eldredge](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1362/nate-eldredge): "Permit Parking for Caltrain Patrons ONLY".

[image]

Comment: Other than the San Fransisco terminus, my impression is that most of the stations are not in areas where parking space is particularly scarce. (In fact my impression of the entire Silicon Valley was something like one giant parking lot with a few office buildings scattered throughout it). Why would people who're not taking the train even want to park at a Caltrain station rather than closer to where they're actually going?

Comment: @HenningMakholm thanks for the downvote... I have my own use cases. Why would I have asked the question otherwise?

Comment: No matter what "your own use cases", you have not substantiated the underlying premise of your question, namely that they _somehow_ check at all. If they don't (and, as I described, I see no reason why they would), then it makes no sense to ask _how_ they do the thing that they do not do.

Comment: @HenningMakholm "they don't check" is a valid answer.

Comment: I've wondered the same about small-town train stations on the US east coast. It's sort of an unspoken secret that they don't usually mind you parking there and walking around downtown, and a search for regulatory signs tends just to reveal the obvious (e.g. must have license plates, park within the lines, don't park in a handicapped space without a permit, etc.), but nothing specifically saying "Parking only for train riders, violators subject to public flogging". As many stations receive both Amtrak and commuter trains, it's unclear who even has authority to determine authority to park.

Comment: You may want to contact Caltrain directly (e.g. via Twitter) to find out if there is actually a rule that *only* Caltrain customers may park in those lots.  In other situations where such a rule exists, a typical method of enforcement is that if you are seen parking your car and then walking somewhere else, you get a ticket or your car is towed.  There may be surveillance cameras to provide proof.

Comment: I did find exactly one photo of a sign saying "Permit Parking for Caltrain Patrons ONLY": https://goo.gl/images/4Xu8AG.  It's not clear whether it is current.

Comment: BTW, "No Camping" is often a euphemism for "no homeless or homeless-looking people".

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks, follow-up: [Which Caltrain stations only have parking for Caltrain customers only?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/131621/1810)

Answer (score 6):

It is nowhere stated on the page you are linking to that the parking lots are not available to non-customers or customers of other train companies.

If you continue reading on the same page, some stations offer free parking. At other stations, you have to pay for parking anyway and there are two options availble:

- a daily parking permit, obviously available to anyone
- a monthly parking permit, only available to Caltrain customers who already have a monthly pass (for the train)

Comment: "It is nowhere stated on the page you are linking to that the parking lots are not available to non-customers or customers of other train companies."  -> Good point, it seems it depends on the Caltrain station. [Which Caltrain stations only have parking for Caltrain customers only?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/131621/1810)