# Which Caltrain stations only have parking for Caltrain train customers only?

Tags: usa, trains, automobiles, california, northern-california

Which Caltrain stations only have parking for Caltrain train customers only?

---

http://www.caltrain.com/riderinfo/Parking.html  indicates which Caltrain stations have parking (e.g. http://www.caltrain.com/stations/mountainviewstation.html -> "340 [parking] spaces; pay through ticket vending machine"), but I couldn't find any information regarding which Caltrain stations  have parking for Caltrain train customers only. Looking at the Caltrain  parking  signs online, I see some mention "Permit Parking for Caltrain Patrons ONLY" or some don't.

E.g., from https://www.parkme.com/en-gb/lot/187135/mountain-view-station-mountain-view-ca, found by [Nate Eldredge](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1362/nate-eldredge): "Permit Parking for Caltrain Patrons ONLY".

[image]

and some doesn't mention it, e.g. from https://www.parkme.com/en-gb/lot/187136/palo-alto-caltrain-station-palo-alto-ca:

[image]

Note that parkme.com doesn't have a picture of the parking sign for each Caltrain station (e.g. https://www.parkme.com/en-gb/lot/225138/sunnyvale-station-sunnyvale-ca).

Comment: Have you read http://www.caltrain.com/riderinfo/Parking.html? That seems to explain the parking rules in some detail.

Comment: @GregHewgill I read it. Does it indicate which Caltrain stations are for Caltrain customers?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt: They all are. From the linked page, *"Caltrain requires that all parking customers have a Daily Parking ticket or a Monthly Parking Permit to park in all Caltrain-owned lots 24/7."*

Comment: @GregHewgill thanks, can't one purchase a daily parking ticket without being a Caltrain customer?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt: No, because if you *buy a parking ticket from Caltrain*, then that makes you a Caltrain customer.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt: No, because all parking tickets for Caltrain owned lots are only available for purchase from Caltrain. You don't have to actually ride the train to be a Caltrain customer.

Comment: @GregHewgill right but do you have to be a Caltrain *train* customer to be allowed to purchase a parking ticket?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt: No. The only way to get a *monthly* parking pass is to buy it in conjunction with a monthly train ticket, but anybody can by a *daily* parking pass. Whether that's an effective use of your parking money is up to you.

Comment: @GregHewgill where did you see daily tickets can be purchased by anyone? When the sign in the first picture of the question says "Permit Parking for Caltrain Patrons ONLY", I interpret it as one has to be a Caltrain train user, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I would ask Caltrain on Twitter. They're very responsive.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience in a number of cities, parking maintained by the authority or agency will have such restrictions unless the parking lot is shared with another facility.

Again from experience, I would not expect this specific detail to be published since they probably just never thought to do so.

FYI, how the 'customer only' restriction is often enforced is by putting the parking payment facilities *inside the fare zone*.  Meaning, you can only pay for parking after buying or having a ticket and passing through a gate or turnstile.

However, this may not apply to all Caltrain stations as I recall some have turnstiles while other have an open platform.  Again, I doubt this specific detail is published since, to Caltrain, it doesn't matter.

Does buying a Caltrain ticket make you technically compliant?  Probably, but who know how far they take enforcement.

Comment: Caltrain is a proof-of-payment system.  No stations have turnstiles or any other strictly enforced form of access to the platform (the exception being 4th/King, where they will normally check tickets as you enter the platform - but there's no parking there so it's not relevant)